# A problem on characteristic values.

Tags: linear-algebra

If the characteristic values of
 $\begin{pmatrix}
  3 & -1 \\
  5 & 6 
  \end{pmatrix}$

are $a$ and $b$.

And of

$\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 \\
  -1 & 5
  \end{pmatrix}$
Are $c$ and $d$.
Then the equation whose roots are $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}$ and $\frac{1}{c} + \frac{1}{d}$ is

$(a)$.  $201x^{2} - 161x + 54 = 0$

$(b)$.  $161x^{2} - 201x + 54 = 0$

$(c)$.  $201x^{2} +161x - 54 = 0$

$(d)$.  $161x^{2} + 201x - 54 = 0$

Characteristic equation for both matrices are respectively $y^{2} - 9 y+23 = 0$ and $y^{2} - 6y +7 = 0$
Now, I don't have any idea where to go. Roots of this equation can be found, but calculations become quite complicated. Is there any other way to solve$?$

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$
\frac1a+\frac1b=\frac{a+b}{ab}=\frac{9}{23}
$$
and you have a similar relation for the other number.

Comment: Yes, it's $\frac{trace}{det}$ and answer is b. Thanks.

Comment: @Mathsaddict You’re welcome